# Code throws Error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, integration, plsqldeveloper

Can someone explain to me why this error occured?

```sql
SELECT CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY, 'Projection', '1', OPEN_BALANCE,
  PRINC_REPAYMENT, INTEREST, PAR_PREPAYMENT, FULL_REDEMPTION, REDRAW_AMOUNT, PRIN_DEFAULTS,
  PRIN_RECOVERY, PRIN_DEL, INTE_DEL, DEL_PRIN_COLL, DEL_INT_COLL, CLOSE_PRIN_BAL, EXT_ID,
  LAS_ACTIVE_FLG, PROD_ID, ASSET_TYP_ID, CPT_ID, ACCRETION, CASHFLOW_DT 
FROM FACT_PWOR_CASHFLOW
WHERE ACTUAL_FLG = 'Y' AND LATEST_PROJ_IND = '0' AND LAS_ACTIVE_FLG = 'Y'
UNION
(SELECT CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY_COLL, 'Actual', '1', SUM(OPENING_BALANCE) SUM_OPEN_BAL,
    SUM(MI_PRINCIPLE) SUM_MI_PRIN, SUM(MI_INTEREST) SUM_MI_INTER, SUM(PARTIAL_PREPAYMENT) SUM_PAR_PREPAY,
    SUM(FULL_REDEMPTION) SUM_FULL_REDEM, SUM(TTL_AMT_REDRAW) SUM_TTL_AMT,
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', SUM(CLOSING_BALANCE) SUM_CLOS_BAL, '0', 'Y',
    PROD_ID, ASSET_TYPE_ID, CPT_ID, '0', COLLECTION_START_DT
FROM FACT_PWOR_COLLECTION
WHERE LAS_ACTIVE_FLG = 'Y'
GROUP BY CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY_COLL, PROD_ID, ASSET_TYPE_ID, CPT_ID, COLLECTION_START_DT
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID, DATEKEY_COLL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is pretty common and it occurs because you have an `ORDER BY` in your nested query (see where you use the parenthesis in the second `SELECT`).
Oracle doesn't support that so it gives you this error. You could either rewrite it without the nested query, or remove the order by and it should work